# normalizing a belongsTo response

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm using Ember Data : 1.13.9
and I'm trying to normalize my response. Using the RESTSerializer.

I have two models.

venues and setting.

they are 1-to-1 relationship.

```
venue model
DS.Model.extend({
  settings: DS.belongsTo('settings')
})

settings model
DS.Model.extend({
  venue: DS.belongsTo('venue')
})
```

my settings response looks like this:

```
{
  "order_rounding":null,
  "order_rounding_method":null,
  "category_persistence":null
}
```

I'm trying to normalize to:

```
{
settings: {
  "order_rounding":null,
  "order_rounding_method":null,
  "category_persistence":null
}
}
```

in my serializer for venue i've added links to the settings

```
normalize: function(modelclass, resourceHash, prop) {
  links: {
    settings: '/venues/' + resourceHash.id + '/settings'
  }
}
```

I've tried all the normalize hooks and cant seem to format the response. Anyhelp would be great.
thanks ahead of time!

Answer (score 0):

Ugh.. I forgot to set the property for the Serializer. I believe this is going to be default for anything above 1.13.

isNewSerializerAPI: true